# Will vault dwellers heal over time?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I'm recovering from a *serious* rad-roach infestation. All my surviving dwellers are injured and/or have serious radiation poisoning (red bar).

Do I have to heal every dweller, or (assuming I have sufficient water/food) will they heal themselves over time? Does radiation poisoning go away by itself too?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your dwellers will recover over time (health and radiation) **if** you have enough food and water **and** if they are currently in the vault.

If you lack food, your dwellers will lose health slowly.
If you lack clean water, your dwellers will get irradiated slowly.

Comment: Good answer, but I'd like to add that in my experience the health recovery is VERY slow and if you leave someone with low health (say below 50%) they'll start to lose happiness.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they will recover but it will be very slow and if you have an irradiation higher than 50% or same amount of lost health points, it's not really worth to wait. **They will quickly become very unhappy** and it's gonna be harder to get back 50, 60 people to 100% happiness (or close). Start creating stampacks and radaways and slowly heal everyone, starting with the most affected ones of course.

**What I usually do after something like this, I use a cycle of 1 radaway to each affected dweller (until all the radaway are gone), even though that doesn't completely heal them but stops the rapid happiness decline.**

Answer (score 0):

I just suffered a feral ghoul attack. Hitting my top-floor Dining Area, my mid-high level dwellers suffered approximately 20% health loss and 10% rad poisoning. I used no stims and no radaway, and they self-healed within about ten minutes. High endurance dwellers appeared to heal faster.

Answer (score 0):

They do not heal over time if they are working in a room, but they seem to heal quickly if they are on coffee break.  Once you get to more than 70 dwellers you can expect almost constant deathclaw attacks so it doesn't matter anyway.  You will need at least three fully upgraded and staffed medbays to produce enough stimpacks.

Answer (score -1):

Actually they don't heal one bit & over time, instead they max out the health of any dweller that levels up.

As for radiation, only Radaway gets rid of it, so you will have to produce them.

If the dwellers health is so low as to not be able to withstand the next attack before they level up then I would suggest healing via Stimpacks.

Comment: Dwellers do heal over time without leveling. Just don't expect it to happen while you watch... it's much slower than that.

Answer (score -1):

You can fully heal them by using Radaway and Stimpak but use both of them so it can heal completely

Comment: Unfortunately, this adds nothing to the already existing answers.