# Do dwellers heal in the wasteland in Fallout Shelter?

Tags: fallout-shelter

When I send dwellers to the wasteland for long periods of time, they usually use their RadAways and Stimpaks.

This time, I sent out a dweller with the maximum 25 RadAways and Stimpaks, with a Fatman and Heavy Wasteland gear. I have noticed that she heals, and that her radiation lowers, but her RadAway and Stimpak counters to not decrease.

She still has all 25 after 13 hours. I have watched the bars go up and down. I can not tell if this is deliberate, or a bug, but the movements are supported by the log.

Is it possible for dwellers to heal, and for their radiation to lower, by themselves?

Comment: How noticeable is the healing? Is it she goes out with a tiny bit of room on both bars, and over 13 hours it fixes, or does she get into some serious combat, and magic-heal? It appears a [similar question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/232441/will-vault-dwellers-heal-over-time) has been asked, and healing should only happen inside the vault.

Comment: It's more like half health, about a quarter of radiation, then almost full health and no radiation at all, while no radaway nor stimpak was consumed.

Comment: Have just checked on it now, still 25 both, a speck radiation and almost full health. and in the last hour she suffered around 30 damage, while it was mostly 1 - 2 damage per fight, there was also 4 damage and so. But I don't really know how much health they have, might be important she's level 36, has 7-S, 1-P, 10-E, 6-C, 6-I, 4-A, 4-L.

Comment: Have you checked the journal?  Maybe they found some and that made it appear like they never used any.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it's not possible for dwellers to heal by themselves in the wasteland. However, dwellers heal all damage when they level up in the wasteland.

> But I don't really know how much health they have, might be important she's level 36, has 7-S, 1-P, 10-E, 6-C, 6-I, 4-A, 4-L.

You said it yourself, she is not level 50. There you go. And because she has 10 Endurance, she hardly takes any radiation damage.

---

I try to max dweller stats before I send them out to level, so I have a level 8 dweller with 25 stimpacks and high `+E` gear and a big gun take about 2 days before they use the first stimpack. That's because with every level up their health and radiation will reset. In addition, [if they have more than 10 Endurance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/223912/29763), they will never take radiation damage (red bar).

[image: screenshot]

I didn't have an undammaged dweller right now, but I think it's obvious that this guy would not survive 4 days with only 6 stimpacks without having some additional healing going on. I believe he was level 8 when I sent him out.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know they heal all damage when they level up. that's what I wanted. :)

Answer (score -3):

real I might just be possible your dweller did not take any damage in those first 13 hours.

I have experienced (anecdotical) that dweller will loose health and eat up stimpacks at an exponential rate (or so it seems); first it goes slowly, then it goes fast.

Comment: Well she did suffer damage, it was written in that journal, or log, whatever it is that the dwellers write while out in the wasteland.

Comment: The exponential rate you are seeing is because they encounter stronger creatures and those do more damage. Hence their health drops faster and they need to take more stim packs.

Comment: Indeed, @simbabque, the dweller gets to fight from Bloatflies to Centaurs.