# Healing Speed Bonus

Tags: fallout-shelter

I got my first pet today and she came with the bonus of x3 Healing Speed. Obviously it affects healing speed, but I've never noticed my dwellers gaining health back without use of stimpacks.

I'm very curious what this actually does so I can determine if it would be better to send her out with my exploring dwellers or keep her back in the vault for emergencies.

Comment: Dwellers do heal over time. See [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/232441/will-vault-dwellers-heal-over-time?rq=1).

Answer (score 2):

Healing speed applies to dwellers in your vault.  They will heal over time if food level are sufficient.